# PostgreSQL JSONB data type for a column performance for OLTP database

Tags: postgresql

PostgreSQL v13

I am analyzing the use JSONB data type for a column in a table.

JSONB will be one of the column in the table. The idea is to get flexibility. The information (keys) stored inside the JSON will not be same every time and we may add keys overtime. The JSON object is expected to be under 50 KB and once written will not be changed.

My concerns/questions :

1. This is an OLTP db and requires high read/write performance. Any performance issues with JSONB data type ?
2. Does having JSONB lead to more bloat in the table and hence we may suffer overtime ?

In general pls share your experience with JSONB for such use-case.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `jsonb` sounds like good for your need. The jsonb column can be indexed for improving the performances, but the final performance will highly depend on the queries you execute in the database, the database configuration and on the rest of the architecture (server size, network lag time, ...)

Comment: What will be the values in the JSON, just numbers and strings? "*we may add keys overtime*" - you could also achieve that by adding nullable columns to a table.

Comment: How are you going to use the data? Do you have to extract data from these json objects or not? Do you have search for content within these objects or not? If so, what kind of indexes are you going to use?

Comment: @FrankHeikens We would **not** to extract data from json object nor we would search within the content. We will read them in full. I have not thought about the indexes yet.

Comment: @Bergi it would be just numbers and strings. I understand that we can use null-able columns however this is the very reason we want to use JSON data type as we either have too many columns in a table or many different tables.